# Fan Operation Anomalies

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hpe

I'm encountering a perplexing issue with the fan operation on a server, specifically the DL380p model. There are two primary concerns I've been unable to address through online resources:

The first issue revolves around the uneven running of the fans. Presently, the initial three fans from the left operate at 32%, the fourth at 34%, and the last two at 42%. Is this fluctuation in fan speeds an expected behavior?

The second problem is related to the fans running consistently at the same speed regardless of the temperature. I experimented by setting the thermal configuration to "optimal cooling" in the ROM settings. Even with the installation of the "Agentless Management Service" into Proxmox, which showed as functioning correctly in iLO, the fans did not ramp up in speed, remaining unchanged even when the CPU package temperature reached 85 degrees Celsius during a stress test.

Initially, the server was running an old firmware. To troubleshoot, I upgraded all possible components using the SPP iso and subsequent firmware updates over the following month. I've also performed numerous resets of both ROM and iLO, each reset with a new firmware upgrade. Despite these efforts, the cooling issue persists. I attempted fan swaps as well, but the same inconsistent behavior persisted.

Comment: Is there an actual issue, or is it simply that you want to see equal figures? I have never even bothered to check fan metrics on servers unless they give me an alert on temperature or fan failure.

Comment: @vidarlo just mentioned the uneven fan speeds in case it could be related to the second problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The first issue revolves around the uneven running of the fans. Presently, the initial three fans from the left operate at 32%, the fourth at 34%, and the last two at 42%.

Depending on the exact system in question, that may be entirely normal. Different fans usually serve different temperature zones.

Check those temperature zones for unusual temperatures - *then* you may complain about fans running at abnormal speed.

> Is this fluctuation in fan speeds an expected behavior?

That's no fluctuation (a least not by your description). A fluctuating fan would change its speed wildly, without any reason/temperature change. Most often its bearing is noisy as well and then it surely needs replacement.

> The second problem is related to the fans running consistently at the same speed regardless of the temperature.

That is more of a problem. If the OS doesn't handle the fan speed, the BIOS/UEFI firmware needs to. Configure the BIOS settings accordingly.

Comment: I had tried changing the power settings in bios as well as resetting it with iLO, the fans always run on static speed as whatever is set in bios thermal configuration, I had to bump it from optimal cooling to increased cooling to workaround it temporarily, i am running out of ideas what to try, i have read somewhere else that these fans aren't software controllable, only if the software communicates with firmware, as far as i got with installing hp-health on proxmox is missing libraries that aren't available for bookworm

Answer (score 0):

The fans are controlled by the ILO, which intelligent enough to know when to adjust fan speed.

I don't see a problem here. Most folks are actually interested in [LOWERING the fan speed](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/hix44v/silence_of_the_fans_pt_2_hp_ilo_4_273_now_with/) on this platform.

Here's fan output from three different DL380p Gen8 servers under my management:

```
[root@las ~]# hplog  -f
ID     TYPE        LOCATION      STATUS  REDUNDANT FAN SPEED
 1  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 11)
 2  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 34)
 3  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 43)
 4  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 43)
 5  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 43)
 6  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 43)


[root@ppro ~]# hplog  -f
ID     TYPE        LOCATION      STATUS  REDUNDANT FAN SPEED
 1  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   (  6)
 2  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   (  6)
 3  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   (  6)
 4  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 34)
 5  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 43)
 6  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 43)


[root@ftp ~]# hplog  -f
ID     TYPE        LOCATION      STATUS  REDUNDANT FAN SPEED
 1  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   (  6)
 2  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   (  6)
 3  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   (  6)
 4  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 34)
 5  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 43)
 6  Var. Speed   Virtual         Normal     Yes     Normal   ( 43)
```

Comment: Well I do see a problem with package reaching 85 degrees, according to intel ark. T CASE for my cpus is 86 degrees